# Building a particular vector of names in R

Tags: r

I have `n*m` variables of the form `x = (i,j,a,b)` where `i,j=1,...,n` and `a,b=1,...,m`.
We always have `i<=j` and `a<=b`.

They form the rownames of a (sparse) matrix I want to build in R.
For example, the first row would be called `1,1,1,1` and the second one would be `1,1,1,2`.
No row will be called `2,1,1,1` since `i<=j` and similiarly no row will be called `1,2,3,2` since `a<=b`.

How can I automatically set these rownames in the matrix. The order is not important.

Comment: You can use `expand.grid` to create all the permutations and then a logical statement to extract the rows that meet your criterion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making up some data here. But you can create all the possible combinations using `expand.grid()` then exclude the combinations you don't need based on your rule. Then construct a character vector, and then use it as the labels for the row names of the matrix.

```
X <- expand.grid(i = 1:3,
            j = 1:3,
            a = 1:3,
            b = 1:3) %>%
    filter(i <= j & a <= b) %>%
    mutate(label = paste(i, j, a, b, sep = ",")) %>%
    pull(label)

matrix(data = NA, nrow = length(X), ncol = 4, dimnames = list(X))
```

First few rows of output

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
1,1,1,1   NA   NA   NA   NA
1,2,1,1   NA   NA   NA   NA
2,2,1,1   NA   NA   NA   NA
1,3,1,1   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try the code below

```
n <- 2
m <- 3

p <- subset(expand.grid(rep(list(seq(n)), 2)), Var1 <= Var2)
q <- subset(expand.grid(rep(list(seq(m)), 2)), Var1 <= Var2)

with(
  expand.grid(1:nrow(p), 1:nrow(q)),
  cbind(p[Var1, ], q[Var2, ])
)
```

which gives

```
    Var1 Var2 Var1 Var2
1      1    1    1    1
3      1    2    1    1
4      2    2    1    1
1.1    1    1    1    2
3.1    1    2    1    2
4.1    2    2    1    2
1.2    1    1    2    2
3.2    1    2    2    2
4.2    2    2    2    2
1.3    1    1    1    3
3.3    1    2    1    3
4.3    2    2    1    3
1.4    1    1    2    3
3.4    1    2    2    3
4.4    2    2    2    3
1.5    1    1    3    3
3.5    1    2    3    3
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an attempt to solution your question :

```
n = 2
m = 2
i = 1
a = 1

df <- expand.grid(i:n, i:n, a:m, a:m)
df[ !(df$Var1 > df$Var2 | df$Var3 > df$Var4) ,]
apply(df, 1, paste,  collapse = ' ')
```